# jQuery Show not working if css class has display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a class called loading like this:

```
.loading {
   display: none;
   vertical-align: top; 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   background: url('../images/shared/loading_16x16.gif') center center no-repeat; 
   width: 16px; 
   height: 16px;
}
```

with following html snippet:

```
<div id="loading" class="loading"></div>
```

and my jQuery code (on document ready):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#loading").show().children().show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#loading").hide().children().hide();
    }
});
```

But `show()` is not working at all. Even if I trigger it from the chrome developer window.
On the chrome developer window if I uncheck the `display: none` from the loading class then the tag appears.

What's happening?

Comment: Is the request happening so quick you can't see it?

Comment: `$("#loading").hide().children().hide();` is unnecessary by the way. Visibility is inherited.

Comment: have you tried just running the breforeSend part?

Comment: I believe the issue is that the ajax call executes and completes almost immediately. Show has a delay of 300 MS by default and therefore if your ajax function executed in 50MS it would hide before the element became visible.

Comment: Javascript has a higher precedence over css rules since it applies the rules inline. What i'm guessing is that the rule applied on a different element and that you have a selector issue. try running it manually and see where it's being applied.

Comment: The ajax call last more than 300ms by the way

Comment: why not remove display: none; from .loading class and hide/show loader using jquery

Comment: Can you take out the `.hide()` line? I want to know if the `#loading` element appears and stays visible when the request is made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out!

I fix it by doing this on my jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function () {
         $("#loading.loading").show();
     },
     complete: function () {
         $("#loading.loading").hide();
     }
});
```

Hope helps to some else :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend:beforeSendFunction(),
      complete:onCompleteFunction()
  });
  });
  function beforeSendFunction(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          $("#loading").show();
      },2000)
  }
  function onCompleteFunction(){
      $("#loading").hide();
  }
```

you can remove setTimeout function in beforesend ,

here is the working jsfiddle link,i replaced background image to background color:" [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mAka/)"

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$("#loading").show();` instead of that `$("#loading").show().children().show();`

You trying this in local instance, though it is completed very fast, so that you can't able to view `loading`.

To verify the same, you just dump the loading hide line from your code and you can try, now you can find the loading text.

```
      complete: function () {
               // $("#loading").hide();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are mixing classes with ids.
In your css you have a `.loading` which is a class, but in your jQuery you use id selector `$("#loading")` . Your jQuery simply can't find the element.

Comment: Why not? #loading is valid selector for the div.

Comment: Look at the `HTML`. `loading` id and class selectors exist.

Comment: The element is founded with the #loading selector

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have come across this problem myself and there is a much simpler solution. Just remove the class.

```
$('#loading').removeClass('loading');
```